# How to check If a DateTime's date is equal to some specific Date

Tags: ruby

It's possible to compare `DateTime`s and `Date`s directly:

```
d = Date.new(2016, 6, 27)
dt = DateTime.new(2016, 6, 22, 10, 12, 11)

d > dt   # => true
d <= dt  # => false
```

However, using the `==` operator to check if a `DateTime`s date is the same as some `Date` always returns false, even when they have the same date:

```
d = Date.new(2016, 6, 27)
dt = DateTime.new(2016, 6, 27, 10, 20, 59)
d == dt  # => false
d >= dt  # => false
d < dt   # => true
```

I supposed, in this case, `d` will be coerced into the equivalent of `DateTime.new(2016, 6, 27, 0, 0, 0)`, which would explain `d < dt` being true.

So, how can I check if `dt` has the same date as `d`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When formulating the question, I figured `DateTime` should have a method to get its date part alone. I looked for it then I found [`DateTime#to_date`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-to_date):

```
d == dt.to_date  # => true
```

Should as well just post the answer, since I found no straightforward results for this on Google.